# Show that $\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{x}{a}\lfloor{\frac{b}{x}\rfloor}$ but $\lim_{x \to 0+}\lfloor{\frac{x}{a}\rfloor}\frac{b}{x}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Show that if $a>0$, $$\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{x}{a}\lfloor{\frac{b}{x}\rfloor}=b/a$$ but $$\lim_{x \to 0+}\lfloor{\frac{x}{a}\rfloor}\frac{b}{x}=0$$
>   Discuss the left hand limits of these two functions.

Attempt

$$\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{x}{a}\lfloor{\frac{b}{x}\rfloor}=\lim_{y \to +\infty}\frac{1}{ay}\lfloor{by\rfloor}{\overset{?}{=} \frac{b}{a}}, ~~~1/x=y$$ how to go further for this and other parts.

Comment: Since $y$ is large floor(by) convergrs to $by$,

Comment: "Show that..." ??

Comment: @DonAntonio Corrected. Please give me the answer.

Comment: @user1942348 What are the assumptions on $\;a,b\;$ ? They both seem to be different from zero...is that all? If they both are zero you've already good answers, and the second one even gives you a huge hint on the second limit.

Comment: @DonAntonio I want to solve it by transformation as I have used.

Comment: @user1942348 It's just the same, but with your transformation it is messier, longer and less clearer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: Assuming $a,b>0$.

The first limit: note that 
$$
\frac{x}{a}\left\lfloor\frac{b}{x}\right\rfloor=\frac{x}{a}\left(\frac{b}{x}-\left\{\frac{b}{x}\right\}\right)=\frac{b}{a}-x\cdot\text{bounded function}
$$

The second limit: note that for $0<x<a$ you get $\left\lfloor\frac{x}{a}\right\rfloor=0$.

Comment: Please elaborate 2nd one

Comment: @user1942348 When $x\to 0^{+}$ it must become less then $a$ after a while, so the function is $0\cdot \frac{b}{x}\equiv 0$, i.e. *identically zero*, for all $0<x<a$. The limit of the zero function is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're asking, but I'm assuming that you mean: $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{x}{a} \lfloor \frac{b}{x} \rfloor = \frac{b}{a}$. You can obtain this using the Squeeze Theorem; $\frac{b}{x} - 1 \leq \lfloor \frac{b}{x} \rfloor \leq \frac{b}{x}$.

The second limit is actually the harder one since you're dealing with an indeterminate form ($\lfloor \frac{x}{a} \rfloor =0$ as $x \rightarrow 0^+$, but $\frac{b}{x} \rightarrow \infty$). The limit of the upper bound has to be $\frac {b}{a}$, so we know the limit is bounded and can't be equal to $\infty$.

Comment: Then the second limit seems to be easier since $\;\left\lfloor\frac xa\right\rfloor=0\;$ and thus that is the limit of the constant $\;0\;$ , which of course equals zero.

Comment: How $\;\left\lfloor\frac xa\right\rfloor=0\;$, if $x>a$